# How to use older version of Maven?

Tags: java, windows, maven, downgrade

I installed newer version of Maven on my Windows machine. But with newer version of Maven I am failing to build an existing app. Is it possible to define in application configurations to use an older version of maven? But the older one is not installed on my machine.

Comment: First question: What does it mean: `failing to build an existing app`..furthermore you can of course install older versions of Maven..just download it and run it?... Download page or https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/

Comment: You can also use maven wrapper and specify the version you want to use https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper

Comment: Newer java versions require that the maven plugins used are updated to the newest or builds will break.

Comment: @Oleg That was not the question and will not help here...

Comment: @khmarbaise I see you're involved with maven so I assume you're right but don't see how. I posted an answer explaining how to use maven wrapper to build an application with an older version of maven. Please explain how it will not help, thank you.

Comment: Which JDK version are you using? Or do you need to use?

Comment: Thanks guys. Using wrapper was a solution I did not know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [maven-wrapper](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper). For example if you want to build with version 3.5.4 do:

```
mvn -N io.takari:maven:0.7.7:wrapper -Dmaven=3.5.4
```

and then when you run:

```
mvnw package
```

Your project will be built with `3.5.4` version of maven.